# How to correctly remap a key binding in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I'd like to remap CTRL-X to work exactly like CTRL-U. Using

```
bindkey "^x" kill-whole-line
```

seems to work, but introduces a slight delay in killing the line in comparison to CTRL-U which works instantly. Also hitting `CTRL-X` multiple times brings up history entries, clearly not what I need.

I assume the issue is caused by the regular CTRL-X functionality which needs to be unbound first, but so far I failed to find the correct command for it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the cause of the delay on hitting `^X`: zsh is waiting for a second key for all the default `^X` sequences. One solution I found to get `^X` to work exactly like `^U` could be to remove all default `^X` sequences, but this is pretty brittle and I'm open for more suggestions.

```
bindkey -r "^X^B"
bindkey -r "^X^F"
bindkey -r "^X^H"
bindkey -r "^X^J"
bindkey -r "^X^K"
bindkey -r "^X^N"
bindkey -r "^X^O"
bindkey -r "^X^U"
bindkey -r "^X^V"
bindkey -r "^X^X"
bindkey -r "^X*"
bindkey -r "^X."
bindkey -r "^X1"
bindkey -r "^X="
bindkey -r "^XA"
bindkey -r "^XG"
bindkey -r "^XM"
bindkey -r "^XP"
bindkey -r "^XS"
bindkey -r "^Xb"
bindkey -r "^Xf"
bindkey -r "^Xg"
bindkey -r "^Xi"
bindkey -r "^Xp"
bindkey -r "^Xr"
bindkey -r "^Xs"
bindkey -r "^Xu"
bindkey -r "^Xz"
bindkey "^X" kill-whole-line
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl-v` to be able to insert `Ctrl-x`, thus make this way

```
bindkey "^V^x" kill-whole-line
```

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. I think my issue is because of this default binding: `"^X*" expand-word`. The delay I'm seeing is probably because it's waiting for a second key after entering ^X. I've yet to find out how to remove this default binding.